# Image I need to replicate.. what tool to use?

Tags: image-processing, networking, uml, diagram

I'd like to replicate as much as possible this type of image for my own network setup... What tool would replicate this as easy as it gets?

[image: google-cloud]

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: You know that this diagram is a much UML as British is French?

Comment: Not necessarily but it requires advanced UML that is unlikely to be understood by the recipient. This can still be UML provided you use profiles. Yet I wouldn't go down this path. Any diagramming tool can support such diagram, this particular was most likely created in Visio.

Comment: @Ister: I have successfully drawn such "advanced UML" diagrams, specifically to represent networks, and then validated them with people who are *not* knowledgeable on UML. They looked pretty much just like the picture above. The benefit to using a standardized diagram and metamodel is that it's not just an inert diagram. You can generate reports, network configuration scripts, and so on from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw this using either a UML composite structure diagram or a SysML internal block diagram. Some tools, like MagicDraw (which you can evaluate for free), even allow you to use networking equipment images.